Negating "He will sink unless he swims"
I want to negate "He will sink unless he swims" using the formula $$\neg (P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv P \wedge (\neg Q).$$
But first, how do we write that statement as if-then statement?

"A  unless B" is usually read in English as "A, if not B". And we can use the truth-functional equivalence between "if not B, then A" and "B or A".

"If he does not swim, then he will sink"

Eventually , you want to get "he will not swim and he will not sink" , which is the negative !

I think 'unless' means, 'either he doesn't swim, and sinks, or does swim, and doesn't sink'.

@Empy2 If we represent he swims as $p$ and he sinks as $q$, your statement reads like $(\neg p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)$ which is $p \oplus q$. This is different from $p \lor q$, which is what OP's statement is "he swims or he sinks". The key difference is your statement is false when he swims as well as he sinks, but OP's statement is still true if he sinks even when he swims

@EnEm Yes that is the difference between our interpretations.  I think the speaker hopes he won't sink if he swims.

@Empy2 Ah yes, I guess it can have two interpretations. I think its usually implied when said "$p$ unless $q$", that the probability of $p$ will decrease when $q$, but it still won't drop to zero technically. Your intepretation is decreasing it to exact zero.

Re: "Please provide additional context..." We have here a simple, unambiguous question asked in good faith with evidence of some thought put into it by the OP.  It should not require a detailed rationale. Voted to reopen.

"He will sink unless he we swims" = "If he doesn't swim, he will sink" = $(\lnot swim)\implies sink$.  The negation, as you point out is $(\lnot swim)\land (\lnot sink)$= "He won't swim and he won't sink".

[If post is reopened, will convert to Answer.] Let the domain be the set of all future timepoints, $W$ represent "he swims" and $K(t)$ represent "he sinks at time $t$".
Then "He will sink unless he swims" is symbolised as$$\lnot W\to\exists t: K(t).$$ Its negation is then $$\lnot W\land\forall t:\lnot K(t),$$ that is, "He does not swim yet will not sink."
This task does not really require predicate logic, which I'm utilising just to draw attention to the given sentence's tense choices.

@ryang How about $\forall t\in R:[\neg W(t) \implies \exists t'\in R: [t\leq t' \land K(t')]]$? The negation would be  $\exists t\in R: [\neg W(t) \land \forall t'\in R :[t\leq t' \implies \neg K(t')]]$.

...Better to stick to the present tense for introductory examples IMHO.

@DanChristensen If you change the ≤ to <, and specify your domain as all possible timepoints (different from the domain that I'm using), then Yes. I'm using the most minimalist FOL translation just  to make a point about tense accuracy, the lack of which potentially causes confusion down the line when the reader starts interrogating the conditional.

Here, we are predicting the future:

"He will sink unless he swims".

It might help to recast this statement as a statement about the present:

"He is sinking unless he is swimming?"

This also removes any suggestion of causality since we are talking only about a single instant in time--the present in this case.
From Mauro's equivalence in comments above, we would then have:

"If he is not swimming, then he is sinking."

The negation would be:

"He is not swimming and he is not sinking."

